# Nginx - failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/example.com

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2

My website is running on nginx + php-fpm and running well but while uploading file it shows blank page.My log file shows

```
2016/06/08 14:44:40 [error] 22063#22063: *25 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(up/propic/medium/5961465411480.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/example.com/saveimg.php on line 32" while reading response header from upstream, client:...
```

I tried most of answers from stackoverflow , even I changed the /var/www folder permissions to 777 but the results are same.

Few details about my server

/etc/php-fpm.d

```
 user=nginx
 group=nginx
```

ownership and group of /var/www/sites

```
drwxrwxrwx. 29 ec2-user root 4096 Jun  8 14:39 site1.com
```

Comment: What is the parameter of "file_put_contents" function resolves to? Looks like it is

    *something*/up/propic/medium/5961465411480.jpg

so you need to check permissions of every single folder on the way to *something*/up/propic/medium/5961465411480.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After searching , I found it.It's all deals with SELINUX which is a security feature.
when using ls -Z

```
drwxrwxrwx. ec2-user root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 www
```

change this to

```
drwxrwxrwx. ec2-user root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 www
```

using cmd

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www
```

Comment: that's right. the answer was here : stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021

Comment: Oh my this was a bug for me all weekend! Thank you so much! Saved me!

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You've saved my day. I got a similar problem with AppArmor on openSUSE.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check permissions and ownership of every folder on the way from

```
/var/www/sites/
```

to

```
/var/www/sites/site1.com/up/propic/medium
```

Answer (score 0):

The user and group defined in your pool.d configuration require access rights to your nginx root location. This can be done by changing the user and group in your pool.d configuration to the same user and group that own your nginx root location or by adding the pool.d user to the group that owns your nginx root location. You can do that like this:

```
usermod -a -G groupName userName
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
# nginx error.log echo:
2019/10/12 11:11:02 [error] 3871#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
Unable to open primary script: /www/test.php (Permission denied)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.9, server: _, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "192.168.1.180"
```

In Centos System, After searching , I found it.It's all deals with SELINUX which is a security feature. when using `ls -alZ`

```sh
drwxrwxrwx. ec2-user root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 www
# change this to
drwxrwxrwx. ec2-user root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 www

# using cmd
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /www
```